# how to execute eof in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, eof

Sorry,this is my first question to use this platform.
As title,when I run the cell,I don't know how to input eof,
I know in Windows OS which can use Ctrl+Z, Linux OS which can use Ctrl+D,
but in Jupyter Notebook, these command don't work on it. Thanks.

```
#p10222 https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/102/p10222.pdf
keys = "`1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]\\asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./"
codes = []


while True:
    try:
        codes.append(input())
    except EOFError:
        break

#codes = input()
#print(codes)

for i in codes:
    for c in i:
        c = c.lower()
        if c in keys:
            print(keys[keys.index(c)-2], end='')
        else:
            print(i, end='')
    print()
```

[demo Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVH3j.jpg)

Comment: how to stop input with eof command in jupyter notebook

Comment: If you mean to interrupt, there is an interrupt kernel button on the top.

Comment: to catch that interrupt change the `except` to: `except KeyboardInterrupt:`